# WARNING: Replicate resource: progressBox

Tags: java, tomcat, zk

I am using ZK as a UI front and I am getting the following error on server startup:

```
WARNING: Replicate resource: progressBox
Overwrite jar:file:/D:/app_servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.16x64/webapps/MyAPP/WEB-INF/lib/ProgressBox-4.0.jar!/metainfo/zk/lang-addon.xml
```

With the jar: `file:/D:/app_servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.16x64/webapps/MyAPP/WEB-INF/lib/ProgressBox-4.0.jar!/metainfo/zk/lang-addon.xml`

This error is repeated for almost all the custom components that is defined for the application.

This error is expected if the jar existed in multiple locations but that is not the case and the error also points to the same jar.

The only change that I have done is that I have added some jars which presents in a different location other than the WEB-INF\lib directory.

What could cause such an error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class path do not contain multiple versions of jars.

Comment: yes i have checked that, it doesnt have multiple version jars